# Seating in a cinema hall

Tags: probability, expected-value

There are $N$ numebered seats in a cinema hall. Each seat has been assigned to a specific spectator. However, the first $N-1$ spectators arrive early and occupy the seats completely randomly. The last spectator wishes to occupy her allotted seat though. So she goes to her allotted seat and then there are two cases

1. if the seat is vacant, occupies it
2. if the seat is occupied then asks the person sitting there to vacate it. The person asked to vacate follows the same pattern : goes to their allotted seat and either sits there if it is vacant or asks the person sitting there to move if occupied. This goes on till everyone is in their correct seats.

What is the expected number of displacements caused in this process?

Comment: Just to clarify, does the process start when the displaced person belongs in the currently empty seat?  Or does every person in the theater have to end up in the correct seat?  And if every person has to end up in the right seat, what's the process for getting people to move if they don't get moved by the initial "displacement chain"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mu_k$ denote the expected number of displacements if there are $k$ specators.

Then: $$\mu_k=\frac{k-1}k\cdot(1+\mu_{k-1})=\frac{k-1}k+\frac{k-1}k\mu_{k-1}$$

One step further we find:$$\mu_k=\frac{k-1}k+\frac{k-1}k\mu_{k-1}=\frac{k-1}k+\frac{k-1}k\left(\frac{k-2}{k-1}+\frac{k-2}{k-1}\mu_{k-2}\right)=\frac{k-1}k+\frac{k-2}{k}+\frac{k-2}{k}\mu_{k-2}$$This makes us suspect that for $n<k$:$$\mu_k=\frac1k\sum_{i-1}^n(k-i)+\frac{k-n}k\mu_{k-n}$$ and this can be verified by induction.

This leads to $$\mu_N=\frac1N((N-1)+\cdots+1)+\frac1N\mu_1=\frac12(N-1)+0=\frac12(N-1)$$

Comment: How did you write the first equation?

Comment: The probability that the last spectator finds his seat unoccupied is $\frac1k$. If that happens then there will be $0$ displacements. The probability that he finds the seat occupied is $\frac{k-1}k$. If that happens then the person on that seat must discplace. He stands up and goes looking for his seat, so the whole process starts over, but now one person (the last spectator) less is involved. This gives $\mu_k=\frac1k\cdot0+\frac{k-1}{k}\cdot(1+\mu_{k-1})$.

Answer (score -1):

The expected number of displacements caused in this process are $\frac{N-1}{2}$ because no matter how many people are at the cinema hall, on the average,exactly one of them will select his own seat. So the expected number of displacements are $\frac{N-1}{2}$.

Letting $X$ denote the number of spectators that select their own seats, we can best compute $E[X]$ by noting that

$X=X_1+X_2+...+X_N$ where $X_i=\left\{{1,\mbox{if the ith spectator selects his own seat}\atop 0,\text{otherwise}}\right.$

Now, because the ith spectator is equally likely to select any of the N seats, it follows that

$P(X_i=1)$=P(ith spectator selects his own seat)=$\frac1N$

and so

$E[X_i]=1*P(X_i=1)+0*P(X_i=0)=\frac1N$

Hence,we obtain

$E[X]=E[X_1]+...+E[X_N]=(\frac1N)*N=1$. Hence, no matter, how many people are at the cinema hall, expected number of spectator who will select his own seat is exactly 1

So the expected number of displacements are $\frac{N-1}{2}$

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  You may have distinct groups that are sitting in each other's seats.  If person A is in person B's seat and person B is in person A's seat, assuming one of them is not the last person to enter, they don't have to move.